# Calculate MSE of two images

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I'm trying to calculate the MSE of two images using the following code:-

```
void getMSE(const Mat& I1, const Mat& I2)
{
Mat s1;
absdiff(I1, I2, s1);       // |I1 - I2|
s1.convertTo(s1, CV_32F);  // cannot make a square on 8 bits
s1 = s1.mul(s1);           // |I1 - I2|^2

Scalar s = sum(s1);        // sum elements per channel

double sse = s.val[0] + s.val[1] + s.val[2]; // sum channels


    double mse  = sse / (double)(I1.channels() * I1.total());

    printf("mse = %f", mse);

 }
```

It's not running successfully and I was wondering if you guys had any idea? Would this code not run if the image sizes were different? VS10 says I have a runtime error, which is vague to say the least!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What exact runtime error are you getting?
On the line "double sse..." you are assuming all the images have 3 channels, while on the next line you are getting I1.channels().
Maybe you should add an assert on the first line like this: I1.channels() == I2.channels() && I1.channels() == 3

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the images have to be the same size. If they don't have the same size, how can `absdiff` do an element wise subtraction? `getMSE()` should check whether `I1` and `I2` are the same size, and if they are not raise an exception or somehow make them the same size (e.g. by padding or [`resize()`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation%29)).

e.g.:

```
 Mat I2_resized;
 resize(I2, I2_resized, I1.size());
 absdiff(I1, I2_resized, s1);
 ...
```

Your code is adapted from [an OpenCV tutotial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-input-psnr-ssim/video-input-psnr-ssim.html#videoinputpsnrmssim) - it looks right to me, so just make sure the images have the same size.

Comment: Please could you let me know how I can resize to make both images the same dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

using python we can calculate MSE of two images.

For this first import numpy library and then take two images img1, img2 and use the code below to print the result

**Code=>**

```
import numpy as np
Y = np.square(np.subtract(img1,img1)).mean()
print("MSE:", Y)
```